# How deep can I #define?

Tags: c++, emoji

I need to use `#define` and `using   =   ;` as much as I can to replace possibly everything in C++ with emojis .

Is it possible to #define preprocessors like `#define  #define` or at least `#define  if`, `#define  ==`, etc.? Maybe with 'using'?

I'd like to replace operators, core language instructions... Is it possible anyhow?

I know the aboves doesn't work, but maybe there is a way?... Please help me make something funny! :D

Comment: See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers for the section that begins "The following Unicode character ranges are allowed in identifiers:"

Comment: Preprocessor directives like `#define` can't be substituted without changing the compiler; But you're free to use `#define` to replace every keyword and operator in C++ with an emoji. As long as your compiler accepts UTF characters in the emoji range.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can. You may need to think about the syntax. Easiest would be to use one emoji per keyword. However you may still need to write function- and variable names in clear text.

As per Romens comment I tried it and you can also replace method names with emojis.

Just as a proof of concept, the following code compiles in visual studio 2019 with platform toolset v142.

```
#include <iostream>

#define  int

 () {
    std::cout << "I'm !";

    return 1;
}

 main() {
    ();
}
```

Or even more to include some of the comments:

```
#include <iostream>

#define  using
#define ‍ cout
#define  int
namespace  = std;
 ::‍;

 () {
    ‍ << "I'm";
    ::cout << "!";

    return 1;
}

 main() {
    ();
}
```

Also `using` is something else than `#define`. You will only need the latter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Visual Studio 2019 supports emoji for identifiers. ` () { std::cout << "I'm a foo!"; }` should work too.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I think `(); ` is most hillarious method call I ever wrote :D

Comment: It's worth noting that `g++`'s support for unicode identifiers is limited. It works fine with `clang++` though.

Comment: `using` declarations are useful too! `namespace  = std;` and `using  = ::cout;`

Comment: Is it also possible to use a compiler argument with an emoji to rename the `main` entry point?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, there is a option in Visual Studio, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to #define preprocessors like #define  #define

No, it is not possible to define macros to replace preprocessor directives. (Also, macros cannot expand into directives either).

> or at least #define  if

This is potentially possible. It depends on the compiler what input character encoding it supports. Emojis are not listed in the *basic source character set* specified by the language standard, so they might not exist in the character encoding used by the compiler.

> Maybe with 'using'?

Emojis are equally allowed for `using` as they are for macros.

---

Note that any identifier could be an emoji (assuming they are supported in the first place) including functions, types and variables. Example:

```
struct  {};
struct  {};

int main() {
    {} == {};
}
```

Comment: You can't compare apples and oranges! ... without `bool operator==(const &, const &);` :-)